# How to overwrite method in Python used in another method with mutable arguments in Rust?

Tags: python, rust, struct, pyo3

I have two structs: Struct and InnerStruct. Struct has two methods: `modify_object` that uses `modify_object_inner`. Rust implementation of `modify_object_inner` doesn't matter because I want to implement this method in class that will inherit after my Struct in Python. Function `modify_object` modifies field of Struct of type InnerStruct. I made this code and it compiles:

```
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::PyDict;

#[pyclass(subclass)]
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct InnerStruct {
    #[pyo3(get,set)]
    pub field: i32
}

#[pyclass(subclass)]
pub struct Struct {
    #[pyo3(get,set)]
    pub inner_struct: InnerStruct
}

#[pymethods]
impl InnerStruct {
    #[new]
    fn new(field: i32) -> Self {
        InnerStruct {field}
    }
}

// I had to implement this because of error "error[E0277]: the trait bound `&mut InnerStruct: ToPyObject` is not satisfied"
impl ToPyObject for &mut InnerStruct {
    fn to_object(&self, py: Python<'_>) -> PyObject {
        let dict = PyDict::new(py);
        dict.set_item("field", self.field).expect("Failed to set field in dictionary");
        dict.into()
    }
}

#[pymethods]
impl Struct {
    #[new]
    fn new(inner_struct: InnerStruct) -> Self {
        Struct { inner_struct}
    }
    
    fn modify_object(this: &PyCell<Self>) -> () {
        Python::with_gil(|py| {
            let inner_struct = &mut this.borrow_mut().inner_struct;
            let kwargs = PyDict::new(py);
            kwargs.set_item("object_to_modify", inner_struct).expect("Error with set_item");
            this.call_method("modify_object_inner", (), Some(kwargs)).expect("Error with call_method");
        });
    }
    fn modify_object_inner(&mut self, object_to_modify: &mut InnerStruct) {
        object_to_modify.field = -1
    }
    
}

#[pymodule]
fn my_rust_module(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Struct>()?;
    m.add_class::<InnerStruct>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

But when I tested it with this Python code:

```
from my_rust_module import InnerStruct, Struct
import os

os.environ['RUST_BACKTRACE'] = '1'


class PythonStruct(Struct):
    def __new__(cls, inner_struct):
        return super().__new__(cls, inner_struct)


inner_struct = InnerStruct(0)
ps = PythonStruct(inner_struct)
ps.modify_object()
print(ps.inner_struct.field)  # without overwriting should print -1


class PythonListElement(Struct):
    def __new__(cls, inner_struct):
        return super().__new__(cls, inner_struct)

    def modify_object_inner(self, inner_struct):
        inner_struct.field = 1


inner_struct = InnerStruct(0)
ps = PythonStruct(inner_struct)
ps.modify_object()
print(ps.inner_struct.field)  # without overwriting should print 1
```

I got:

`thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'Error with call_method: PyErr { type: <class 'RuntimeError'>, value: RuntimeError('Already borrowed'), traceback: None }', src\lib.rs:46:71`

If someone knows the answer, please post additionally a source of your knowledge (for example link to appropriate part of doc), because I'm quite lost and don't know how to find answers myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyO3 still needs to keep Rust's borrowing rules. It cannot let you hold two mutable references to the same object at the same time in Rust. But in Python all references are mutable, so how does it do that?

The answer is [`PyCell`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/pycell/struct.PyCell.html). It is somewhat like `RefCell`: a type that dynamically keeps track of borrowing state. When you call a Rust function that requires `&mut self` or `&self`, PyO3 tries to borrow the value in the `PyCell` (mutably or immutably), and raises and exception if it cannot because it is already borrowed.

In `modify_object()`, you take `this: &PyCell<Self>` and `borrow_mut()` it. While this reference is active, you cannot anymore borrow this object. When you call `modify_object_inner()`, PyO3 tries to borrow the same object immutably for `&mut self`, and fails. So the call to `call_method()` fails, and because you call `expect()` on it, the method panics.

There are two possible solutions:

- Never use this method in Rust. Always implement it in Python, and just remove the Rust implementation. If the Python user will not implement it, an exception will be thrown.
- Drop the `borrow_mut()` before you call the method. Like that:

```rust
let guard = this.borrow_mut();
let inner_struct = &mut guard.inner_struct;
let kwargs = PyDict::new(py);
kwargs
    .set_item("object_to_modify", inner_struct)
    .expect("Error with set_item");
drop(guard);
this.call_method("modify_object_inner", (), Some(kwargs))
    .expect("Error with call_method");
```

Here, when you call the Rust method, the object is no longer mutably borrowed.

However, your code has an unrelated error: you implemented `ToPyObject` for `&mut InnerStruct`, but this code just creates a dict. The dict has no correlation to the original object, and mutating either won't influence the other.

What you need is to hold a [`Py<InnerStruct>`](https://docs.rs/pyo3/latest/pyo3/struct.Py.html) in your struct instead of just `InnerStruct`. `&Py` implements `ToPyObject`, so you can pass it to Python and watch the changes.

You also no longer needs `borrow_mut()`, only `borrow()`, and if you notice that in `modify_object_inner()` you also only need `&self` (or even just `&PyCell<Self>`, that doesn't borrow the object at all), you can keep the Rust implementation of `modify_object_inner()` (as two shared references are allowed to live together).

Another two points is that you don't need `Python::with_gil()`, you can (and should) instead take `py: Python<'_>` as parameter and PyO3 will automatically do everything required, and that using `expect()` and panicking is a bad idea: you should return `PyResult` and propagate the error. If you panic, you get a special `PanicException` that shouldn't be caught. But if you propagate the error, you get a normal exception. While panicking on the dictionary set may be fine (because it will fail if the item is not hashable, and it is), you don't want to panic if e.g. someone removed the `modify_object_inner()` method in a subclass, you want a normal exception that can be caught.

Here's the proposed Rust code:

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::types::PyDict;

#[pyclass(subclass)]
pub struct InnerStruct {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    pub field: i32,
}

#[pyclass(subclass)]
pub struct Struct {
    #[pyo3(get, set)]
    pub inner_struct: Py<InnerStruct>,
}

#[pymethods]
impl InnerStruct {
    #[new]
    fn new(field: i32) -> Self {
        InnerStruct { field }
    }
}

#[pymethods]
impl Struct {
    #[new]
    fn new(inner_struct: Py<InnerStruct>) -> Self {
        Struct { inner_struct }
    }

    fn modify_object(this: &PyCell<Self>, py: Python<'_>) -> PyResult<()> {
        let inner_struct = &this.borrow().inner_struct;
        let kwargs = PyDict::new(py);
        kwargs.set_item("object_to_modify", inner_struct)?;
        this.call_method("modify_object_inner", (), Some(kwargs))?;
        Ok(())
    }
    fn modify_object_inner(&self, object_to_modify: &mut InnerStruct) {
        object_to_modify.field = -1;
    }
}

#[pymodule]
fn my_rust_module(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_class::<Struct>()?;
    m.add_class::<InnerStruct>()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

And the Python code:

```py
from my_rust_module import InnerStruct, Struct
import os

os.environ['RUST_BACKTRACE'] = '1'


class PythonStruct(Struct):
    def __new__(cls, inner_struct):
        return super().__new__(cls, inner_struct)


inner_struct = InnerStruct(0)
ps = PythonStruct(inner_struct)
ps.modify_object()
print(ps.inner_struct.field)  # Prints -1


class PythonListElement(Struct):
    def __new__(cls, inner_struct):
        return super().__new__(cls, inner_struct)

    # Notice the name! It should match the name of the keyword argument you're passing!
    def modify_object_inner(self, object_to_modify):
        object_to_modify.field = 1


inner_struct = InnerStruct(0)
# And here there was a typo, it should be `PythonListElement`, not `PythonStruct`!
ps = PythonListElement(inner_struct)
ps.modify_object()
print(ps.inner_struct.field) # Prints 1
```

Comment: Thank you for a long explanation and working code!